# How could I use SplitEdge method in llvm

Tags: c++, llvm

I need to insert a basic block into an edge. I tried to use SplitEdge method in the following link:
http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/BasicBlockUtils_8cpp_source.html
I found an answer here: 
http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2010-July/033288.html
But, I don't want to set it in runonFunction,, how could I use it without facing the problem of pass does not equal null
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way will be to copy the implementation of the `SplitEdge` method to your own code and modify them to work when the pass is NULL. In the current implementation, it means to modify it to call your own version of `SplitBlock`, and in that version just add `return new` before the calls on `P`.

However, if you do these sorts of operations on LLVM IR, consider doing them from within a proper pass - it will make your code play far more nicely with existing passes.